# Managing lifecycle, using Netflix Governator, of java object without Annotations

Tags: java, guice, governator

Is there a mechanism for me to manage the lifecycle of java objects using [Netflix governator](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/wiki/Lifecycle-Management) without the `@PostConstruct` and `@Predestory` annotations.

I would like to manage the lifecycle of objects within a library that I do not have the power to modify - I create the objects using Providers (hence, I do not need the `@Inject` annotation on them).